# Generative Art in Python- Upstream Logic causing "Invalid Literal for int()"

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, valueerror, argv, sys

I'm a novice coder working on a small generative art exercise to make space-invader sprites, have been stuck on this for a while even though it's probably a trivial problem. The goal of the code is to allow the user to define their own inputs in the command line for a grid of sprite characters, like this:

python spritething.py [SPRITE_DIMENSIONS] [NUMBER] [IMAGE_SIZE]

'''

```
    import PIL, sys, random
    from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

    origDimension = 1500

    r = lambda: random.randint(50,255)
    rc = lambda: ('#%02X%02X%02X' % (r(),r(),r()))
    listSym = []
    def create_square(border, draw, randColor, element, size):
        if (element == int(size/2)):
            draw.rectangle(border, randColor)
        elif (len(listSym) == element+1):
            draw.rectangle(border,listSym.pop())
        else:
            listSym.append(randColor)
            draw.rectangle(border, randColor)

    def create_invader(border, draw, size):
        x0, y0, x1, y1 = border
        squareSize = (x1-x0)/size
        randColors = [rc(), rc(), rc(), (0,0,0), (0,0,0), (0,0,0)]
        i = 1
        for y in range(0, size):
            i *= -1
            element = 0
            for x in range(0, size):
                topLeftX = x*squareSize + x0
                topLeftY = y*squareSize + y0
                botRightX = topLeftX + squareSize
                botRightY = topLeftY + squareSize

                create_square((topLeftX, topLeftY, botRightX, botRightY), draw,            random.choice(randColors), element, size)
                if (element == int(size/2) or element == 0):
                    i *= -1;
                element += i

    def main(size, invaders, imgSize):
        origDimension = imgSize
        origImage = Image.new('RGB', (origDimension, origDimension))
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(origImage)
        invaderSize = origDimension/invaders
        padding = invaderSize/size
        for x in range(0, invaders):
            for y in range(0, invaders):
                topLeftX = x*invaderSize + padding/2
                topLeftY = y*invaderSize + padding/2
                botRightX = topLeftX + invaderSize - padding
                botRightY = topLeftY + invaderSize - padding
                create_invader((topLeftX, topLeftY, botRightX, botRightY), draw, size)
        origImage.save("Examples/Example-"+str(size)+"x"+str(size)+"-"+str(invaders)+"-"+str(imgSize)+".jpg")

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]), int(sys.argv[3]))
```

'''

When I run this code I get a value error from the last line where the argv's are soposed to go. but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong upstream. Any help greatly appreciated.

'''

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call 
         15 
         16 if __name__ == "__main__":
    ---> 17     main(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]), int(sys.argv[3]))

    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '--ip=127.0.0.1'
```

'''

Comment: You're initializing your game with three command line arguments. One of them is obviously not what you were expecting (`--ip=127.0.0.1`). Where is this command line argument coming from?

Comment: Thanks for responding, I'm sort of baffled that the IP came up here. This was in VScode, when I run it in VIM I get the following error which is just the name of the file:  
  File "/Users/perico/spell.py", line 50, in <module>
    main(int(sys.argv[0]), int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]))  
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'spell.py'

Comment: It looks like VSCode was injecting this `--ip` argument for some reason. As for your most recent error, `sys.argv[0]` will always be the name of the script. YOUR command line arguments start at index `1`.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what Ive been looking for, I've been confused about where to index. When I start the index at 1 instead I get the following error in VIM:   File "/Users/perico/spell.py", line 50, in <module>
    main(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]), int(sys.argv[3]))  
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: In this case, the `IndexError` means that you are not passing in the correct number of command line arguments when you run your script, possibly none. How are you running your script?

Comment: kind of embarrassing but im I'm actually so new to programming I dont know the different ways to script. Today Ive tried this on the code-runners extension in VScode, running chunks at a time in a python terminal, and trying to run it from the bash terminal, but it sounds like I'm missing something obvious

Comment: No worries. I've posted an answer that's hopefully helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've got a Python script `script.py`:

```
import sys

print(sys.argv)
```

And you run it from the terminal via:

```
python script.py firstarg 123 thirdarg
```

The output will be:

```
['script.py', 'firstarg', '123', 'thirdarg']
```

Notice: `sys.argv` is a list of strings, where each string represents one of the command line arguments passed in when the script was initially executed. Also notice that the first command line argument will always be a string with the script file's name. Even if you run the same script with no "custom" command line arguments, your program will always get at least one command line argument by default (the script's name.)

---

EDIT - Here is the image that's generated when I run your script (no changes):

[image]

Comment: You've resolved a huge issue for me, this has been a multi hour ordeal. Currently running $ python3 spell.py 7 30 1900 and getting back ['spell.py', '7', '30', '1900']. However the intended document is not being saved as a .jpg unfortunately

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you get any errors? When I run your script it generates the JPG. I've edited my answer and included the generated image.

Comment: Okay finally I resolved the problem, creating .jpgs from the command line successfully. I know this is probably elementary but you've helped me more than you can imagine.  I believe I was encountering the following problems: when trying to run the .py file from VScode and VIM I was downloading the latest version of pillow which is compatible with py 3.9+. I'm using an old mac os (10.13) which python 2.7, tried setting py2 to py3 through .bashrc file but for some reason the computer was "forgetting" i did this after a few minutes and changing it back to 2.7 which was incompatible w/ Pillow 9.0

Comment: @forhayley Happy to help! Glad it's working!